# How to enhance a reflection in post?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop

I took this picture this weekend: 
[image: Child looking at catfish with reflection]

When I took the picture I didn't notice the reflection, but now that I see it, I'd like to enhance it in post. Is there any way to do this?

Technical notes. Shot in RAW, overcast outdoors with no flash, 400 ISO, 1/180, f/8, no polarizer, Pentax K10D.

I use and am familiar with Photoshop CS2

Comment: This doesn't help you now, but in the future: take a polarizing filter to the aquarium. Turned one way, it will reduce the reflections, and turned the other, it will enhance them. Can't be recreated in post-processing, though.

Comment: Enhancing in post is possible, yes, but it'll be pretty creepy, what with the gaping holes where her eyes should be and the skull-ish look her face will have and all. Any part of her reflection that's significantly darker than what's in the aquarium is unrecoverable.

Comment: I think this is good as it is. There is a way to do what you request, a super big sucking, hundred hour, manual repaint. I would do it if the shot is incredible and not reproducible. But I guess you should just go again, and be smarter about taking the photo next time...

Comment: very cool.. i didn't know about polarizing filters and now can't wait to use it with my x100s :)

Comment: @mattdm. Yeah, I always have my polarizing filter with me (didn't actually use it this time) but had I used it this time it would have been to eliminate the reflection. I wasn't trying to capture that, it just happened and I thought that perhaps I could tweak it some.

Comment: @WillP - In your raw developer, can you crank up the exposure to recover some of the eyes in the reflection?  If you can, then you can develop the image just for reflection, even if it completely washes out everything else.  Because, you can use Photoshop to add a masked layer of just the new, brighter, reflection to add *subtle* enhancements to the original reflection..... And by subtle, I mean the less-is-more approach to Photoshop.   If you are able to recover some the shadows in the reflection, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

]I got something a little bit better. First off I don't know what's going on with the color management when it's still in sRGB) butopefully maybe my workflow will give you some ideas.

What I did was convert to LAB and created a mask based on the a channel modified by curves. I.e. I isolated everything that was not green.
I did some fussing around with the mask to get everything that was not the girl or the reflection black.

I then used an L curve to accentuate to girl on an adjustment level using the mask.![enter image description here]

I then did an apply image (subtract, offset 128, rato 2) and then applied that layer using linear light mode. I then repeated this. This step increases the difference between the original and the modified version.

I think the key is converting to LAB and creating the mask based on the a channel. Come to think of it, you might try darkening the green.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try processing the RAW three times optimised for -

1. the girl herself
2. the reflection, and
3. the rest of the scene

Then combine those 3 as layers in Photoshop using layer masks to bring out the relevant parts of the different parts of each layer. You could also try experimenting with blending modes to see if any of those help.